# How can I show my news/blog post's page comments on my facebook post as comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am new on FB API. I don't know how I can show comments of my website's page on facebook's post (relevant to that page)

Please help me on showing my website's page comments (will be done by users with proper facebook auth) on specific post of facebook